# Hiding toolbar in CoordinatorLayout after scrolling down

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

Here is my try for hiding `ToolBar` after Scrolling down:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </WebView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I need to when `WebView` scrolling down, The `ToolBar` hided.

How we can do that?

**As always, my style is:**

`Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put WebView in NestedScrollView:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

But, after thet, I have hardly scrolling on the horizontal axis. Please, post the comment if you find proper solution.